# Is it preferred/okay to use structure-initialization ({...}) over memset, etc.?

Tags: c++, c, windows, initialization

Code:

```
WINDOWPLACEMENT wplcmt = {sizeof(WINDOWPLACEMENT)};
```

Looks so much cleaner than:

```
WINDOWPLACEMENT wplcmt;
memset(&wplcmt, 0, sizeof(WINDOWPLACEMENT));
wplcmt.length = sizeof(WINDOWPLACEMENT);
```

The assembly output of this thing is also pretty nice, for longer structures MSVC even uses `memset` instead of `xor eax, eax` and `mov`'s. And from standard point of view it also looks ok. But I'm still scared about border cases where the structure is not tightly packed say `#pragma pack(128)`, and windows suddenly decides to do a memcmp of the structure.

So is it good/bad to use such syntax?
Is it good practice to use such initializations?

Comment: This sounds like a trolling question.

Comment: Either is fine IMO, but why would Windows (or anything else) memcmp the structure? Doing a memcmp on a structure that has unused bits is surely not sensible in the first place. There is no requirement that those unused padding bytes be zero (or any other value) so any comparison which considered them would be invalid. Does anything actually do that or are you worrying about it "just in case?"

Comment: Once it's out of your code, you can't be sure what happens next. So I'm just wondering how to write cleaner and more robust code.

Answer (score 8):

The second code you show,

```
WINDOWPLACEMENT wplcmt;
memset(&wplcmt, 0, sizeof(WINDOWPLACEMENT));
wplcmt.length = sizeof(WINDOWPLACEMENT);
```

is beyond horrible. Obfuscation, inefficiency, verbosity, you crammed it all into that.

The first code snippet,

```
WINDOWPLACEMENT wplcmt = {sizeof(WINDOWPLACEMENT)};
```

is, except for the obfuscation, the preferred way, unless you want to

- spend more time needlessly writing more code,
- have readers spending more time reading and needlessly analyzing your verbose code,
- get less efficient execution, and
- provide bug entry portals.

By the way, what's with the obfuscated name you used, `wplcmt`?

Why are you obfuscating names?

Is your question real or is it simply trolling?

Cheers & hth.,

**EDIT**: the question has been edited. The above questions were in response to the original title/question, "How evil is this structure allocation?". I'm leaving my answer as-is to provide context for the comments.

**EDIT 2**: the context has changed even further: the OP's nick changed from "Madman" to "Coder". So, while the original was about "How eveil is" normal code by "Madman", it's now about "Is it preferred..." by "Coder". Oh well, I mean, I'm not calling him "Madman" in the commentary, as it would appear now; it's what he called himself, his nick at the time.

Comment: I like the single liner approach better, but as I mentioned, padding and memcmp can break havoc. Say I have struct {int32_t v1, int16_t v2 /*nonexisting padding int16_t*/}, I initialize with = {}, but the library I call, initializes another copy of the same structure with ZeroMemory or memset and does the memcmp. The padding value in my structure is undefined, right, and can return that the structures are different even though actual member variables are equal. Sorry for the obfuscation, it was just a hypothetical code, I tend to use well readable names everywhere.

Comment: Your answer is good (factually), however, you should not accuse other people for no reason. Because of this, your answer won't earn my vote...

Comment: @Madman: if you can, just avoid libraries that check whether padding bytes are zero. or that exhibit other Undefined Behavior. :-)

Comment: @jpalecek: i'm not accusing, just asking, and it's not for no reason, it is for the reasons stated. consider: a "Madman" who presents Microsoft-like low-level C code tagged as C++, and asks how "evil" more normal code is in comparision, conveying the impression that it can't be better. to me that sounds like trolling

Comment: C/C++ is because although I write C++ as much as possible, no one has converted the WINAPI to C++, at least AFAIK. Therefore, if someone knows a clean C++ solution, it's welcomed. Concerning more normal, so far we have 2 completely opposite answers, so even though I like the solution you defend as well, I'm not yet convinced it's good.

Comment: @Alf: These naming conventions and the `memset` mess has been for many years *idiomatic practice on Windows.* As your post is needlessly hostile, I can't give +1. you are correct, but you are very unfriendly about it.

Comment: @greyfade: I'll leave it as-is to provide context for the comments. However, the context for my reply has changed since the question has been edited (it's now not trollish question, as it was when I replied). Cheers,

Comment: The `memset` as written is kind of verbose...  I would prefer `memset(wplcmt, 0, sizeof(wplcmt)); wplcmt.length = sizeof(wplcmt);` so that the type name is not duplicated. But otherwise your statement is inflammatory. If you need to initialize fields to zero and you are working with a library that needs a structure size as a field this is perfectly reasonable. Yes it does an extra write at the end. Big deal. Some compilers (GCC at least) even treat `memset` as a builtin inline function so it's conceivable that it might even detect this and remove redundant writes.

Answer (score 7):

Use memset. Then everyone immediately sees what the code does and it's very unlikely to have any unexpected side-effects.

Comment: +1. I agree. Especially since this is a long-time idiom for initializing native Windows structures.

Comment: ... If we care about being "idiomatic" and native-Windows-specific, shouldn't be be using ZeroMemory() rather than memset()? :)

Comment: What if the structure has a pointer type and pointer is not all bits zero, or floating point value which also might not be all bits zero, IIRC?

Comment: Then we also set those values explicitly afterwards. The documentation for a given Windows class will tell us what should be done to initialize it.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of initialization I fight with constantly. In C99 one can do:

```
WINDOWPLACEMENT wplcmt = {.length = sizeof(wplcmt), .showCmd = SW_SHOW};
```

And the other values are zero-initialized.

In G++ you can do:

```
WINDOWPLACEMENT wplcmt = {length: sizeof(wplcmt), showCmd: SW_SHOW};
```

And lastly in C++, you can choose between initializing all members, or hope that you get the member order right like this:

```
WINDOWPLACEMENT wplcmt = {sizeof(wplcmt)};
WINDOWPLACEMENT wplcmt = {sizeof(wplcmt), 0, SW_SHOW, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}};
```

In fact in this last case, I'm not even sure all C++ compilers support compound literal initialization. Furthermore If the members change order, or type, and your values still fit you won't get an error.

Personally I choose to use C99 where I can, I would declare the struct you've given in one hit, with all the known values up front like this:

```
WINDOWPLACEMENT const wplcmt = {.length = sizeof(wplcmt), .showCmd = SW_SHOW};
```

### Update0

It would seem that the "initialize all" I referred to is only for arrays? My mistake, this makes C++ slightly more usable.

Comment: "WINDOWPLACEMENT wplcmt = {sizeof(wplcmt)}; // all members are set to sizeof(wplcmt)"
Aren't the other values set to 0?

Comment: By "in G++", you mean "in GNU C++", i.e. "with compiler extensions supported by `g++`", yes?

Comment: nice DOUBLE DECLARATION! what does it meeean?

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: Yes I do. `-std=gnu++*`

Answer (score 0):

memset should have better performance because usually it's written in high optimized asm

Comment: memset is emmited most of the time, if the structure is large enough, at least with MSVC

Answer (score 0):

If you use Visual Studio I strongly encourage you to use:

```
WINDOWPLACEMENT wplcmt;
SecureZeroMemory((LPVOID)&wplcmt, sizeof(WINDOWPLACEMENT));
wplcmt.length = sizeof(WINDOWPLACEMENT);
```

because the optimizing compiler could totally remove the **memset** call from your generated code, causing a lot of headaches if you really need to set those values to zero.

**SecureZeroMemory** will never be removed.